# Button generated inside javascript code to onclick insert value in input type text in form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I have a very nice SEO-keyword suggestion tool working with CKeditor, it displays the most used word in the text while writing. The problem is that I want to make these generated keywords clickable one by one. So when you click on a keyword, it auto-fills an input-type text.

Here is the HTML code:

```html
    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="editor1">Insert your text here </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="editor1" name="editor1"><p>text example with ahöäåra</p></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- KW density result -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="editor1">Suggested SEO keywords</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">                     
    <div id="KWdensity" ></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    $(initKW);
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('contentDom', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
    $(initKW);
    });
    });
    function KeyDensityShow(srctext, MaxKeyOut, keylenMin) {
    var Output;
    var words = srctext.toLowerCase().split(/[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+/u)
    var positions = new Array()
    var word_counts = new Array()
    try {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i]
    if (!word || word.length < keylenMin) {
    continue
    }
    if (!positions.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
    positions[word] = word_counts.length;
    word_counts.push([word, 1]);
    } else {
    word_counts[positions[word]][1]++;
    }}
    word_counts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1]
    })
    return word_counts.slice(0, MaxKeyOut)
    } catch (err) {
    return "";
    }}
    function removeStopWords(input) {
    var stopwords = ['test', ];
    var filtered = input.split(/\b/).filter(function(v) {
    return stopwords.indexOf(v) == -1;
    });
    stopwords.forEach(function(item) {
    var reg = new RegExp('\\W' + item + '\\W', 'gmi');
    input = input.replace(reg, " ");
    });
    return input.toString();
    }
    function initKW() {
    $('#KWdensity').html('');
    var TextGrab = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    TextGrab = $(TextGrab).text();
    TextGrab = removeStopWords(TextGrab);
    TextGrab = TextGrab.replace(/\r?\n|\r/gm, " ").trim(); 
    TextGrab = TextGrab.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").trim();
    if (TextGrab != "") {
    var keyCSV = KeyDensityShow(TextGrab, 11, 3);
    var KeysArr = keyCSV.toString().split(',');
    var item, items = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < KeysArr.length; i++) {
    item = '';
    item = item + '<b>' + KeysArr[i] + "</b></button>&nbsp;";
    i++;
    item = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(thebox).value="head of gwyneth paltrow";"><span class="badge">' + KeysArr[i] + "</span>&nbsp;" + item;
    items = items + item;
    }
    $('#KWdensity').html(items);
    }}});
</script>
```

And here is some extra HTML for the input that needs to be auto-filled.

```
The keywords box:
```

```
 <input type="text" id="thebox" value="" style="width:80%;height:30px;background:#000;color:#fff;"/>
    <br><input type="button" value="this one is working" onclick="document.getElementById('thebox').value='test button is working';">
```

So if you write something, it will generate keywords buttons. When you click on one of these buttons, the keyword must be entered in the input text like this

```
keyword,
```

Here is a [Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rg0myntj/2/).

Any idea how to fix that? I added a `document.getElementById('thebox').` but it does not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in

```js
item = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(thebox).value="head of gwyneth paltrow";"><span class="badge">' + KeysArr[i] + "</span>&nbsp;" + item;
```

Will add to the DOM (in other words, to the HTML of the page), the following bit:

```html
<button
  class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
  type="button"
  onclick="document.getElementById(thebox).value="head of gwyneth paltrow";"
>
```

Now, the resulting `onclick` above has some problems. First, notice that the quotes it uses in the string after `.value=` are actually closing the `onclick` declaration because they are not escaped. I mean, instead of

```js
onclick="document.getElementById(thebox).value="head of gwyneth paltrow";"
                                               ^--- problem here       ^--- and here
```

It should've been

```js
onclick="document.getElementById(thebox).value=\"head of gwyneth paltrow\";"
                                               ^--- fixed here          ^--- and here
```

Secondly, the argument to `.getElementById(thebox)` is `thebox`. Notice here that the way it is now, `thebox` is actually a variable, not a string. So instead of the above, what you want is:

```js
onclick="document.getElementById(\"thebox\").value=\"head of gwyneth paltrow\";"
                                 ^---    ^--- fixed here
```

These fixes should be enough to make the clicks on the words set the `"head of gwyneth paltrow"` value in the textbox.

I believe, though, you want to actually set the key when the button is clicked. To do that, instead of having `"head of gwyneth paltrow"` after the `.value`, you should have the text of the key. All in all, here's how that line could be:

```js
item = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value=\'' + key + '\';"><span class="badge">' + KeysArr[i] + "</span>&nbsp;" + item;
                                                                                              ^--     ^--       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- changed here (notice in the demo below I declare the key variable before using it here)
```

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vd9gw4fu/10/). Running demo below as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
  $(initKW);
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('contentDom', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
      $(initKW);
    });
  });

  function KeyDensityShow(srctext, MaxKeyOut, keylenMin) {
    var Output;
    var words = srctext.toLowerCase().split(/[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+/u)
    var positions = new Array()
    var word_counts = new Array()
    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i]
        if (!word || word.length < keylenMin) {
          continue
        }
        if (!positions.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
          positions[word] = word_counts.length;
          word_counts.push([word, 1]);
        } else {
          word_counts[positions[word]][1]++;
        }
      }
      word_counts.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[1] - a[1]
      })
      return word_counts.slice(0, MaxKeyOut)
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  }

  function removeStopWords(input) {
    var stopwords = ['test', ];
    var filtered = input.split(/\b/).filter(function(v) {
      return stopwords.indexOf(v) == -1;
    });
    stopwords.forEach(function(item) {
      var reg = new RegExp('\\W' + item + '\\W', 'gmi');
      input = input.replace(reg, " ");
    });
    return input.toString();
  }

  function initKW() {
    $('#KWdensity').html('');
    var TextGrab = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    TextGrab = $(TextGrab).text();
    TextGrab = removeStopWords(TextGrab);
    TextGrab = TextGrab.replace(/\r?\n|\r/gm, " ").trim();
    TextGrab = TextGrab.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").trim();
    if (TextGrab != "") {
      var keyCSV = KeyDensityShow(TextGrab, 11, 3);
      var KeysArr = keyCSV.toString().split(',');
      var item, items = '';
      var previousKeys = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < KeysArr.length; i++) {
        item = '';
        var key = KeysArr[i];
        previousKeys.push(key);
        item = item + '<b>' + key + "</b></button>&nbsp;";
        i++;
        item = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value=\'' + previousKeys.join(', ') + '\';"><span class="badge">' + KeysArr[i] + "</span>&nbsp;" + item;
        items = items + item;
      }
      $('#KWdensity').html(items);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="editor1">Insert your text here </label>
<div class="col-md-10">                     
<textarea class="form-control" id="editor1" name="editor1"><p>text example with ahöäåra</p></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<!-- KW density result -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="editor1">Suggested SEO keywords</label>
<div class="col-md-10">                     
<div id="KWdensity" ></div>
</div>
</div> 



The keywords box: <input type="text" id="thebox" value="" style="width:80%;height:30px;background:#000;color:#fff;"/>
<br><input type="button" value="this one is working" onclick="document.getElementById('thebox').value='test button is working';">
```

Comment: Almost perfect, just one thing: if there are 4 keywords and I click on 3, the input text must be filled like this: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3 any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Yeah. For that  you can create a `previousKeys` array, add the keys to it each iteration and use `previousKeys.join(', ')` in the `onclick`. I have updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: OMG it works so perfect this is exactly was I was trying to achieve since a couple of days ago :) Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Sorry again: if I only want to click on keyword number 1 and 4 only it just select all 4 keywords and not these I am clicking only, for example: keyword1 keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword4 keyword5 and I only want to click on keywork1 and keyword4 so the input text gets auto filled with these 2 keywords only, but if I click on keyword 4 the input text gets auto filled with all 4 keywords :( any idea ?

Comment: replace `.getElementById(\'thebox\').value=\'' + previousKeys.join(', ')` with `getElementById(\'thebox\').value += \'' + key`, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, just separated with commas, I cannot make it work with commas like this one, two, tres, four

Comment: try `onclick="document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value = (document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value.length === 0 ? \'' + key + '\' : document.getElementById(\'thebox\').value + \', \' + \'' + key + '\')"><span`

Comment: Yes garotinho this is exactly but exactly what I was looking for :) thanks again and have a very nice day amigo

Comment: Hahah, not a problem 